# Open specific app from Internet Link loop

Tags: macos, firefox

I'm using Firefox with duckduckgo, I search for a [location](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=la%20petite%20floride&t=ffab&ia=web) and it provides me a map on the right with the location I'm looking for.

Clicking on it will show a prompt asking if I want to open it on Apple Maps software. I wanted to open it on a web page so I've put Firefox.app, Clicked "Remember My Choice".

[image: Launch Application]
Same dialog but for maps in my case

Firefox Preferences:
[image: Maps Preference]

Bug:
Firefox enter in a loop opening a tab that opens another tab etc...

Needed:
Remove Firefox from the automatic opened App from OSX Settings when I click on this kind of link (mail.apple.com).

Checked:
http://osxdaily.com/2013/08/08/change-default-application-open-files-mac-os-x/
It's not a file but an URL so I don't know where to change this.

Thanks for any help

Solution:
As @Allan mentioned, I went to the preferences of firefox and changed Apple Maps by Always Ask. It asked me again what I wanted and switched back to Apple Maps. It works now.

Comment: Firefox isn't a mapping service.  You need to select a mapping service (Google Maps, Bing Maps, Here, etc.) to open that link.  If you select Bing Maps, for example, it will open a new tab in Firefox.  With all of that said, I don't see how this is related to Apple hardware, software, or services.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about **website usage** an not about Apple hardware, software, or services as defined in the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @Allan Actually I want to remove this Auto Open Firefox.app from osx. Now each time I click on this url link. iOS opens firefox instead of Apple Maps App causing a loop

Comment: Is this on *macOS* Sierra or on iOS on your iPhone/iPad?  Regardless, this is still not an Apple question because this application association is set in Firefox.  Go into Preferences and look for Applications.  Remove the association you created.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. This is this kind of dialog I've got with Apple Maps.app in first position. I've selected Firefox.app and Remember my choice. For me it's an OSX dialog but I'm maybe wrong (pretty new to this). It's on OSX Sierra has put in the tags, I was hesitant to add it on my post.
There is no Firefox in the application in preferences. Only maps - Apple Maps (Default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Allan et @Gio mentioned, it was in the Settings of Firefox. Even if the software shows already maps like in the screenshot.

[image: Maps in Settings]

Click on maps and change to "Always Ask". Next time you will click on this kind of link, it will reprompt you instead of generating tab loops.

Comment: Feel free to accept your answer, and thanks for writing it up...

Answer (score 1):

If you choose an online service (like Google Maps) from the dropdown menu under the "directions" button, before clicking on the "location" map, it will open in the same tab, using that service (you can cmd+click the map to open in in another tab)

[image: service choosing context menu]

OTH

Comment: Thanks Gio, I didn't know about that. But I'm actually looking to remove the automatic opening of firefox instead of Apple Maps Software.

Comment: as someone else already noted, this is a Firefox question and not a Mac question. However the suggestion given is correct: in Firefox|Preferences..., in the General section, there is the Applications subsection. Write map in the search box above the applications list and select "always ask" as the action to perform when encountering a content of type "maps"

Comment: Thanks I add to force it as "Always Ask" you mentionned.